# Calculate mode of 2 numbers with the same base !!!!

Tags: arithmetic, number-systems

I have 2 numbers with same base(not necessary 10).

I want to calculate the mode(Remainder of the division) of this 2 numbers without changing the base of them.The base of this 2 number can be between 2 to 10.For base 10 the answer is easy but what about the other bases

Is there any way that I calculate the mode of this 2 numbers

For example:
number 1: 1100
number 2: 101
both in base 2
The answer is :10 in base 2

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by your use of "mode"? Are you dividing one number by the other? Is mode being used as in "modular"? Then yes, $1100/101$ has remainder $10$, all in base two. Do you know how to do division in bases other than 10? It works the same way as in base 10.

Comment: Yes I mean the remainder of the division of these numbers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the division algorithm in any base. But you can just convert to any known basis and convert back the remainder:
$$
1100_2=12,\quad 101_2=5,\quad 12\bmod 5=2=10_2
$$

Actually, division in base $2$ is really easy, because it doesn't involve guessing: at each step the quotient is either $0$ or $1$.
$$
\begin{array}{cccc|ccc}
1&1&0&0 & 1&0&1 \\
\\
1&0&1&  & 1&0\\
 & &1&0
\end{array}
$$
(unfortunately MathJax doesn't seem to support `\cline`). In the first step we consider three digits, the quotient is $1$; the subtraction gives $1$ and we consider the next digit. The number $10_2$ is less than $101_2$, so the quotient is $0$ and we're done.

Comment: I can't exactly understand you in the first step I think subtraction gives 9?????

Comment: @Danial It's in base $2$, remember!

Answer (score 1):

You can perform long division of one number (the dividend) by another (the divisor) in any base $n$, where both the dividend and the divisor are in base $n$. The result, as in base 10, yields the quotient (at the top) and the remainder $r$ (at the bottom most row, $0 \leq r \lt $ the divisor).

See, for example, Wikipedia's entry on long division: the subsection on [non-base 10 division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division#Non-decimal_radix).